# what is the logic behind this logical expression

Tags: javascript

```
function expect(argument) {
   this.eat(argument) || this.undefined();
}
```

Can someone please help me explain how this code works... the question is focused on `this.eat(argument) || this.undefined();`. I am guessing that one of those methods would run? and if it is, how do I tell which would run

Comment: The first (from left) would run. If it doesn't return truthy value, then the second would run.

Comment: Also see the [logical OR operator (`||`) documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

Comment: [Logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or Condition `||` will return the first true value.

if `this.eat(argument)` return true or any value which can be converted to true value, So the `this.undefined()` function will not execute.

If not it will execute.